# React ant design form validation not working (on submit)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

When i press submit and if there is nothing filled in email/password a message should appear beneath them saying email/password is required but its not happnening

Code Sandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hypatia-ieepw?file=/src/App.js:0-1221

````
import './App.css';
import {Button, Form, Input, Checkbox} from 'antd'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
  <Form
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{
        remember: true,
      }}
    >
      <h1 className="Title">Sign Up</h1>
      <h2 className="Text">Enter Email :</h2>
      <Form.Item
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your email!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input placeholder="Enter Email" />
      </Form.Item>
      <h2 className="Text">Enter Password :</h2>
      <Form.Item
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your password!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input.Password placeholder="Enter Password" />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item  name="remember" valuePropName="checked">
        <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item >
        <div className="Button">
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" size="medium">
          Submit
        </Button>
        </div>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `name` property for your `Form.Item` components. The `antd` form utilities work with `name`. So, because you haven't defined name for your text input fields, it can not validate or read its value.
You should change your `Form.Item` like this:

```
      <Form.Item
        name="email"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your email!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input placeholder="Enter Email" />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        name="password"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your password!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input.Password placeholder="Enter Password" />
      </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know my response is late, but I hope it will help someone else.
I actually had the same problem a couple of days ago, but my problem was that I had a called method in a Button and not in the Form. And your problem is also that you didn't specify the name properties.

So, first you have to create a method and call it in the Form tag and then you have to specify the name property for each Form.Item component. That will look like this:

`````
import {Button, Form, Input, Checkbox} from 'antd'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

function App() {
const [form] = Form.useForm();
const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(form.getFieldsValue());
    console.log('Success:', values);
    form.validateFields();
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
  <Form form={form}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{
        remember: true,
      }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
    >
      <h1 className="Title">Sign Up</h1>
      <h2 className="Text">Enter Email :</h2>
      <Form.Item
        name="email"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your email!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input placeholder="Enter Email" />
      </Form.Item>
      <h2 className="Text">Enter Password :</h2>
      <Form.Item
        name="password"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your password!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input.Password placeholder="Enter Password" />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item  name="remember" valuePropName="checked">
        <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item >
        <div className="Button">
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" size="medium">
          Submit
        </Button>
        </div>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;````
`````